# How will I determine the number of nodes required to run my private Blockchain Network stable?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, etherscan

I am designing a use case where millions of users will be using it and is expecting a  transaction rate of 50 per second.  I am looking forward to have it on Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your definition of *stable*.

If by stable you mean that it is accessible then you have to look at Azure's estimates/promises about server downtimes and calculate based on those - based on from how many nodes you are planning to issue transactions.

If by stable you mean that there is no latency then in theory 1 node is the optimal as it doesn't need to discuss with any other node.

Most likely you have to make compromises on the amount of nodes based on accessibility / latency / money / something else.

As for the transaction rate, there is some discussion about it here for example: [What is a Private Proof of Authority transaction speed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36565/what-is-a-private-proof-of-authority-transaction-speed)

As I can't give you any real numbers I strongly suggest you to start with a smaller set of (test) users and work your way up from there - you will also need the experience of running Ethereum nodes in whatever platform.